# D3 mouseover is fine on localhost but not on deploy site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, d3.js

I have some D3 plots that look as I would expect on localhost, but I can't figure out why one of these plots has changed slightly on the deployed site. The last plot on [this page](http://douglasduhaime.com/viz) (a cooccurrence plot ala Mike Bostock's Les Miserables example) should highlight the row and column text labels if a user mouses over a cell at position (row, column), but for some reason only the column text is being highlighted.

The relevant mouseover code is as follows:

```
function mouseover(p) {
    d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
        return i == p.y;
    });
    d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
        return i == p.x;
    });
}
```

And the relevant css is here:

```
#cooccurrence text.active {
  fill: red;
}
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/duhaime/shakespearean_characters) to the full working code as it exists on the site.

Does anyone know why the mouseover isn't changing the rows' text labels to red in the last plot? I thought some site-level css might be interfering, but haven't been able to debug the cause yet. I would be very grateful for any insights others can offer on this question!

Comment: I added `console.log(p);` under the mouseover function call for debugging, in case anyone's looking presently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

The code below returns 274 elements as you have some  DOM elements with class `row` and within it there are `text` DOM elements.
Thus the index matches for some other element and makes it red.

```
d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
        return i == p.y;
});
```

The correct selector would be like below:

```
function mouseover(p) {
    d3.selectAll("g .row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
        return i == p.y;
    });
    d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
        return i == p.x;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, good catch @Cyril. This is twice now you've helped me see the light! Would it be alright to use `d3.select("#cooccurrence).selectAll(".row text")` as the selector to make sure I'm only getting the appropriate class within this visualization? That feels more specific to me than the selection on `g`. I just tried this and it works, but I wanted to hear if maybe I should prefer selection on g.

Comment: Now what you trying is the best way to do it!